# Decorating a service with a method that uses $http

Tags: angularjs, angular-decorator

I'm trying to decorate a service with another method. The problem is that method uses `$http` which I can't inject into the `angular.config` block because it hasn't been initialised yet.

I thought I could get around this by using `$injector` as this would only run when the method I add gets called, but this results in the error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $http
```

Here's an example of what I am trying to do:

```
angular.module('someModule', [])

.config(($provide, $injector)->  
  $provide.decorator('someService', ($delegate)->   
    $delegate.newMethod = ()->
      $http = $injector.get('$http')
      $http.get('someURL')
    return $delegate
  )
)
```

Later on, only when I call `someService.newMethod()` do I get the error mentioned above.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Shouldn't you be injecting `$injector` to the decorator as well?

Comment: I should probably move the `$injector` injection to there but I don't think it will make a difference as it'll still be available within via a closure.

Comment: I think that will fix it for you, not sure why but the closure doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You're right! Thanks! If you want to post an answer with that info I'll accept it.

Comment: I've just thought about why this doesn't work - the `$injector` that is returned when injected into a `.config` block is probably not the same one that is injected after all the config has completed - it'll look for a provider with the name you pass it, rather than `[name]Provider`. Makes sense now. Thanks ;)

Comment: Isn't `$injector` a singleton though ? Shouldn't it be the same one wherever you inject it ?

Comment: I think I understood what you meant, yes that makes sense :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the `$injector` needs to be injected to the decorator as well, so this will fix it:

```
angular.module('someModule', [])

.config(($provide, $injector)->  
  $provide.decorator('someService', ($delegate, $injector)->   
    $delegate.newMethod = ()->
      $http = $injector.get('$http')
      $http.get('someURL')
    return $delegate
  )
)
```